# Web Posts\Images Rating - Component Required

Tags: plugins, rating

i am working on some image blog... i need to put the "rate it option"..

i can do this in two ways

- have one thumbs up & one thumbs down image and caption it like it or not and then do my rating with AJAX + MySQL
- second option is display line of stars & all you know...

both methods are common.. but i haven't implemented either on before.. the first one i can do... but i can't do the second one & want to do the second one...

i was thinking if there is something off-the-shelf available which i could use plugin into my leech page that would look something like [this [see the stars under the image]](http://meadk.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/cartoon-lorry-wallpaper/) OR [this [look at top center]](http://www.911tabs.com/link/?2238293)...

Answer (score 1):

Or look at [RateIt](http://rateit.codeplex.com)  , see [some examples](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/